# How does the 'group' argument in rowsum work?

Tags: r, rowsum

I understand what `rowsum()` does, but I'm trying to get it to work for myself. I've used the example provided in R which is structured as such:

```
x <- matrix(runif(100), ncol = 5)
group <- sample(1:8, 20, TRUE)
xsum <- rowsum(x, group)
```

What is the matrix of values that is produced by `xsum` and how are the values obtained. What I thought was happening was that the values obtained from `group` were going to be used to state how many entries from the matrix to use in a `rowsum`. For example, say that group = (2,4,3,1,5).  What I thought this would mean is that the first two entries going by row would be selected as the first entry to `xsum`. It appears as though this is not what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rowsum` adds all rows that have the same group value.  Let us take a simpler example.

```
m <- cbind(1:4, 5:8)
m
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    5
## [2,]    2    6
## [3,]    3    7
## [4,]    4    8
group <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
rowsum(m, group)
##   [,1] [,2]
## 1    3   11
## 2    7   15
```

Since the first two rows correspond to group 1 and the last 2 rows to group 2 it sums the first two rows giving the first row of the output and it sums the last 2 rows giving the second row of the output.

```
rbind(`1` = m[1, ] + m[2, ], `2` = m[3, ] + m[4, ])
##   [,1] [,2]
## 1    3   11
## 2    7   15
```

That is the 3 is formed by adding the 1 from row 1 of m and the 2 of row 2 of m.  The 11 is formed by adding 5 from row 1 of m and 6 from row 2 of m.

7 and 15 are formed similarly.

Comment: Took me some more playing around after using your example to get an understanding, but I do get it now. Thank you for your help.